# What is the difference between RDL 2008 Schema and RDL 2010 Schema? Feature wise

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

What are the feature wise difference between RDL 2008 Schema and RDL 2010 Schema? And which one supports visual studio 2012 Report Viewer? 
I am going to generate dynamic reports using visual studio 2012 c#, to generate xml schema. But want to know that what are the new features that supports in new versions, e.g. collapse ellapse grouping etc

Comment: ellapse isn't a word http://dictionary.reference.com/misspelling?term=ellapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different things.  Let me try to explain it:

RS 2008:

- stores its metadata either in a SQL2005 or SQL 2008 database
- can run RDL 2003/10, RDL 2005/01, RDL 2007/01, and RDL 2008/01.  RDL is the report definition language generated by report designer.

RS 2005:

- stores its metadata either in a SQL2000 or SQL 2005 database
- can run RDL 2003/10 and RDL 2005/01

BIDS 2005 (Report Designer 2005):

- generates RDL 2005/01
- can directly publish to RS 2005 and RS 2008

BIDS 2008:

- generates RDL 2007/01 currently, will be RDL 2008/01 by RTM
- can directly publish to RS 2008, but cannot "downgrade" the RDL.

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: what about the newer report server versions? 2008 is very old now

Answer (score 2):

You can diff the xsd files find the exact differences, but here's the major changes between 2008 and 2010 (2008 R2):

2010

- **A ReportSections list of ReportSection types is added to the top level Report type**

  - Body, Width, and Page tags are moved into ReportSection tag
- **New SharedDataSet type for DataSetType**
- **New Map chart supported**
- Some ChartType fields related to Code are removed
- Some Chart DerivedSeriesFormula enums are removed
- Changed some fields for StateIndicatorType
- Changed some fields for IndicatorStateType

2010: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd

2008: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd

2005: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd